How to constrain a QRubberBand within an image/QLabel?
I'm creating an image viewer in pyqt5, it's all working. I need to add a cropping function where the user can draw a rectangle over the image and the rectangle will be used later.
Currently, it's drawing the QRubberBand perfectly, but I want it to stay inside the image and not draw outside the image like this:

I already tried this:
if eventQMouseEvent.pos().x() < self.imageLabel.size().width() and eventQMouseEvent.pos().y() < self.imageLabel.size().height():
                
    self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.originQPoint, eventQMouseEvent.pos()).normalized())

but it's buggy/blocky and not working as intended.
Here's the full working code so you can recreate the current app:
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap, QPalette, QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QSizePolicy, QScrollArea, QMessageBox, QMainWindow, QMenu, QAction, qApp, QFileDialog, QApplication, QRubberBand
import sys

class QImageViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.scaleFactor = 0.0
        
        self.opened = False

        self.imageLabel = QLabel()
        self.imageLabel.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Base)
        self.imageLabel.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        self.imageLabel.setScaledContents(True)

        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Dark)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.imageLabel)
        self.scrollArea.setVisible(False)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)

        self.createActions()
        self.createMenus()

        self.setWindowTitle("Image Viewer")
        self.resize(800, 600)

    def open(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        # fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", QDir.currentPath())
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()', '',
                                                  'Images (*.png *.jpeg *.jpg *.bmp *.gif)', options=options)
        if fileName:
            image = QImage(fileName)
            if image.isNull():
                QMessageBox.information(self, "Image Viewer", "Cannot load %s." % fileName)
                return
            
            self.opened = True
            
            self.imageLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))
            self.scaleFactor = 1.0

            self.scrollArea.setVisible(True)
            self.fitToWindowAct.setEnabled(True)
            self.updateActions()

            if not self.fitToWindowAct.isChecked():
                self.imageLabel.adjustSize()

    def zoomIn(self):
        self.scaleImage(1.25)

    def zoomOut(self):
        self.scaleImage(0.8)

    def normalSize(self):
        self.imageLabel.adjustSize()
        self.scaleFactor = 1.0

    def fitToWindow(self):
        fitToWindow = self.fitToWindowAct.isChecked()
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(fitToWindow)
        if not fitToWindow:
            self.normalSize()

        self.updateActions()

    def createActions(self):
        self.openAct = QAction("&Open...", self, shortcut="Ctrl+O", triggered=self.open)
        self.exitAct = QAction("E&xit", self, shortcut="Ctrl+Q", triggered=self.close)
        self.zoomInAct = QAction("Zoom &In (25%)", self, shortcut="Ctrl++", enabled=False, triggered=self.zoomIn)
        self.zoomOutAct = QAction("Zoom &Out (25%)", self, shortcut="Ctrl+-", enabled=False, triggered=self.zoomOut)
        self.normalSizeAct = QAction("&Normal Size", self, shortcut="Ctrl+S", enabled=False, triggered=self.normalSize)
        self.fitToWindowAct = QAction("&Fit to Window", self, enabled=False, checkable=True, shortcut="Ctrl+F",
                                      triggered=self.fitToWindow)

    def createMenus(self):
        self.fileMenu = QMenu("&File", self)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.openAct)
        self.fileMenu.addSeparator()
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAct)

        self.viewMenu = QMenu("&View", self)
        self.viewMenu.addAction(self.zoomInAct)
        self.viewMenu.addAction(self.zoomOutAct)
        self.viewMenu.addAction(self.normalSizeAct)
        self.viewMenu.addSeparator()
        self.viewMenu.addAction(self.fitToWindowAct)

        self.menuBar().addMenu(self.fileMenu)
        self.menuBar().addMenu(self.viewMenu)

    def updateActions(self):
        self.zoomInAct.setEnabled(not self.fitToWindowAct.isChecked())
        self.zoomOutAct.setEnabled(not self.fitToWindowAct.isChecked())
        self.normalSizeAct.setEnabled(not self.fitToWindowAct.isChecked())

    def scaleImage(self, factor):
        self.scaleFactor *= factor
        self.imageLabel.resize(self.scaleFactor * self.imageLabel.pixmap().size())

        self.adjustScrollBar(self.scrollArea.horizontalScrollBar(), factor)
        self.adjustScrollBar(self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar(), factor)

        self.zoomInAct.setEnabled(self.scaleFactor < 3.0)
        self.zoomOutAct.setEnabled(self.scaleFactor > 0.333)

    def adjustScrollBar(self, scrollBar, factor):
        scrollBar.setValue(int(factor * scrollBar.value()
                               + ((factor - 1) * scrollBar.pageStep() / 2)))
    
    def mousePressEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        if self.opened:
            self.originQPoint = eventQMouseEvent.pos()
            self.currentQRubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
            self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.originQPoint, QtCore.QSize()))
            self.currentQRubberBand.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        if self.opened: 
            self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.originQPoint, eventQMouseEvent.pos()).normalized())
            
    def mouseReleaseEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
        if self.opened:
            self.currentQRubberBand.hide()
            currentQRect = self.currentQRubberBand.geometry()
            self.currentQRubberBand.deleteLater()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    imageViewer = QImageViewer()
    imageViewer.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_()) 

I found this answer but it's in C++ and I didn't understand anything.

This is the answer, I intersected the rect of the selection from the rect of the image:
def mouseReleaseEvent (self, eventQMouseEvent):
    if self.opened:
        currentQRect = self.currentQRubberBand.geometry()
        self.currentQRubberBand.setGeometry(currentQRect.intersected(self.imageLabel.geometry()))
        

